# Pattern matching - ensure list contains only values of the one struct

Tags: elixir

Let say I have a struct called `%Product{}`. I want to pass list of products to the method:

```
def serialize(products) do
```

Is there any way to pattern match or guard clause of this list to be sure that this list consists only of `%Product{}` structs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible with either pattern matching or guard clauses. You would have to check for this using something like `Enum.all/2` inside the body of the function.

Comment: Kinda interesting - why it's not possible?

Comment: You can't pattern match for the entirety of a list because it wouldn't be efficient.  There is no limit to the length of the list and even asking for the length of the list would be inefficient.  Patterns and guards have the implicit requirement that they are efficient so they can be used to choose different function clauses quickly.

Comment: @LukeImhoff well `Kernel.length/1` is allowed in guards.

Comment: @asiniy well there's no pattern in the language that can be applied to each element of a list argument and the [list of allowed guard functions](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84459) does not have any way to run a predicate on each element of a list. The only (list specific) thing you can do with lists in guards is get its length, its head, or its tail.